# How to run automation anywhere job using REST API?

Tags: ui-automation, rpa, automationanywhere

I would like to run automation anywhere job from 3rd party app.

1. How to invoke Automation Anywhere Job using Rest API?
2. Can we pass some parameter into a job when invoke it from Rest API?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have the control room v.11 to do so, if I am not mistaken. You can see the documentation here if you have access: https://support.automationanywhere.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003173494

You pass parameters to (Control Room URL)/v1/schedule/automations/deploy
Such as:

```
{    "taskRelativePath":"My Tasks\\HelloWorld.atmx", "botRunners":
[{    "client":"BotRunner1", "user":"User1"     }]    }
```